# Select distinct ID on one table with Linq to EF5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The closest that I can get to one distinct record from this table is below. I need to grab all ScacIDs not matching the ScacTaskID. There should be one and only one record returned for each ScacID.

```
 List<ScacSetupTask> taskSetup_recs = db.ScacSetupTasks
                .GroupBy(e => e.ScacID)
                .Select(e => e.First())
                .Where(e => e.ScacTaskID != taskID)
                .ToList();
```

The table is here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<ScacSetupTask> taskSetup_recs = db.ScacSetupTasks
                .GroupBy(e => e.ScacID,(key,g)=>g.OrderBy(x => x.ScacSetupTaskId).First());
```

Comment: Very quick reply, thanks! Trying to make it work. It needs to filter on ScacTaskID not equal to input of taskID. Also needs a .ToList() on the dump end to prevent error on converting IQueryable source to IEnumerable target.  I will continue to work with your solution.

Comment: Is that all? I was hoping you could see the obvious mistake I was making.